# How to create a sidebar for the posts without sidebar layout

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I am using a theme to create a website. However, while creating posts, I found that the post does not have sidebar layout, Then, I tried to use some plugin to add a sidebar to my posts. However, all of them cannot work.

Does anybody know how to add a sidebar to non-sidebar post layout?

Comment: I found a solution in the other post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43932377/creating-custom-sidebar-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom sidebar in the single.php file

Comment: Thank you for your reply. With your advice, I found a solution.